# mem_change in R, should be negative on deleting a vector

Tags: r, memory

Here is a reprex:

```
> pryr::mem_change(x<- 1:1e7)
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr':
  method      from
  print.bytes Rcpp
11.5 kB
> pryr::mem_change(rm(x))
592 B
>
```

My query is when I do mem_change(rm(x)) I should get a negative number since memory used should decrease. Why do I get a positive 592 B ?

```
# Trying to recreate Irina's code on my computer
> library(pryr)
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr':
  method      from
  print.bytes Rcpp
> mem_used()
37.2 MB
> mem_change(x<-1:1e7)
12.8 kB
> mem_used()
37.4 MB
> mem_change(rm(x)) # This should be negative, but it's not
592 B
> mem_used()
37.4 MB
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `mem_used()` to see how big your memory now.
Then when you `mem_change(x<- 1:1e7)`, you you extending you memory for vector x.
The  `mem_change(rm(x))` will just remove this vector and take you back to the initial memory size.
Will be helpful to read [Package ‘pryr’Author Hadley Wickham](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pryr/pryr.pdf)

```
> mem_used()  # how much you use now
253 MB
> pryr::mem_change(x<- 1:1e7)   # add 40MB
40 MB
> mem_used()   # now you have 253 + 40 = 293 MB
293 MB
> mem_change(rm(x))   # deleting 40MB
-40 MB
> mem_used()   # you should see the oroginal memory size.
253 MB
```

Comment: Your mem_change(rm(x)) is negative. On my computer it is not. Why is it like that ? That was my original query. On your computer I think it is working perfectly but not on mine.

Comment: It is not negative, it is "minus 40 MB"  = it is just shows the action was taken: the 40 MB was deleted/subtracted from existed memory, "rm" mean remove x, and in this case it was 40 MB subtracted.

Comment: And in your question 592 B is also decreased, because it was 11.5 KB, and                  1 Kilobyte(KB)  =  1,024 Bytes (B)

Comment: Should it not be "minus 592 B"  in my query ?